# How do I create a augmented plant of a state space model / Transfer function?

Tags: matrices, matlab, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Let's say that I got the transfer function matrix. I can use a state space model if I want it, but in this case, I will use a transfer function matrix:

$$ G(s) = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{5}{s^2 + 3s +6}\\ 
\frac{1}{s^2 + 0.1s +4}
\end{bmatrix}$$

And I set the weighting matrices to:

$$W_1 = \frac{5}{s+1}$$
$$W_2 = \frac{1}{s+1}$$
$$W_3 = \frac{1}{s^2+s + 1}$$

Then I use MATLAB's command augw.m to create the agumented plant of transfer function matrix $G(s)$.
https://se.mathworks.com/help/robust/ref/augw.html

The diagram for the augmented plant is:

[image]

```
>> G

Transfer function 'G' from input 'u1' to output ...

            5
 y1:  -------------
      s^2 + 3 s + 6

             1
 y2:  ---------------
      s^2 + 0.1 s + 4

Continuous-time model.
>> W1

Transfer function 'W1' from input 'u1' to output ...

        5
 y1:  -----
      s + 1

Continuous-time model.
>> W2

Transfer function 'W2' from input 'u1' to output ...

        1
 y1:  -----
      s + 1

Continuous-time model.
>> W3

Transfer function 'W3' from input 'u1' to output ...

           1
 y1:  -----------
      s^2 + s + 1

Continuous-time model.
>> P = augw(G, W1, W2, W3)

P.a =
                x1          x2          x3          x4
   x1           -1           0           0           0
   x2            0          -1           0           0
   x3            0           0          -1           0
   x4            0           0           0           0
   x5            0           0           0           1
   x6            0           0           0           0
   x7            0           0           0           0
   x8            0           0           0           0
   x9            0           0           0           0
   x10           0           0           0           0
   x11           0           0           0           0

                x5          x6          x7          x8
   x1            0           0           0           0
   x2            0           0           0           0
   x3            0           0           0           0
   x4           -1           0           0           0
   x5           -1           0           0           0
   x6            0           0          -1           0
   x7            0           1          -1           0
   x8            0           0           0   4.768e-16
   x9            0           0           0   4.487e-16
   x10           0           0           0          -1
   x11           0           0           0           0

                x9         x10         x11
   x1            0           0           5
   x2            0          -5   1.908e-16
   x3            0           0           0
   x4            0           0           1
   x5            0           0           0
   x6            0          -1   3.816e-17
   x7            0           0           0
   x8    1.476e-15           4  -2.776e-16
   x9    7.167e-16  -1.776e-15        -0.6
   x10   -2.22e-16        -0.1   2.776e-16
   x11          10  -3.553e-15          -3

P.b =
          w1    w2    u1
   x1      5     0     0
   x2      0     5     0
   x3      0     0     1
   x4      0     0     0
   x5      0     0     0
   x6      0     0     0
   x7      0     0     0
   x8      0     0    -1
   x9      0     0  -0.5
   x10     0     0     0
   x11     0     0     0

P.c =
              x1         x2         x3         x4
   z1          1          0          0          0
   z2          0          1          0          0
   z3          0          0          1          0
   z4          0          0          0          0
   z5          0          0          0          0
   v1          0          0          0          0
   v2          0          0          0          0

              x5         x6         x7         x8
   z1          0          0          0          0
   z2          0          0          0          0
   z3          0          0          0          0
   z4         -1          0          0          0
   z5          0          0         -1          0
   v1          0          0          0          0
   v2          0          0          0          0

              x9        x10        x11
   z1          0          0          0
   z2          0          0          0
   z3          0          0          0
   z4          0          0          0
   z5          0          0          0
   v1          0          0          1
   v2          0         -1  3.816e-17

P.d =
       w1  w2  u1
   z1   0   0   0
   z2   0   0   0
   z3   0   0   0
   z4   0   0   0
   z5   0   0   0
   v1   1   0   0
   v2   0   1   0

Input group 'W' = [1 2]
Input group 'U' = 3
Output group 'Z' = [1 2 3 4 5]
Output group 'V' = [6 7]
Continuous-time model.
>>
```

My question is:

The augmented plant in state space form, is displayed as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x}\\ 
z\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix}= P = \begin{bmatrix}
A & B_1 & B_2 \\ 
C_1 & D_{11} & D_{12}\\ 
C_2 & D_{21} & D_{22}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
u_1\\ 
u_2
\end{bmatrix}$$

So how should I interpret this from the terminal:

```
Input group 'W' = [1 2]
Input group 'U' = 3
Output group 'Z' = [1 2 3 4 5]
Output group 'V' = [6 7]
```

Does this explain which matrix represent, from P.a, P.b. P.c, P.d in the terminal, $A, B_1, B_2, C_1 , C_2, D_{11}, D_{12}, D_{21}, D_{22}$ ?

For example:

$C_2$ will be:
$$C_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 3.816e-17
\end{bmatrix}$$

$D_{21}$ will be:

```
         w1  w2  
    z1   0   0  
    z2   0   0  
    z3   0   0  
    z4   0   0
    z5   0   0
```

Right?

The w1 and w2 are reference vectors. In many cases, they are named as r1 and r2.

Comment: $D_{21}$ should be the same height as $C_2$, so 2 instead of 5.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Sorry! I mean $D_{11}$. But am I right about those input and output group representing those matrices?

Comment: $D_{21} = [1 0; 0 1]$